# apt-get install unable to locate package

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

On a virtual machine (OS is Ubuntu 10.10), I'm trying to create Debian package from a Python package using **stdeb**:

```
apt-get install python-stdeb
```

But the terminal says:

```
E:Unable to locate package python-stdeb
```

Comment: Did you run apt-get update? Sometimes that does wonders

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it didn`t help

Comment: You should upgrade your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.10 ceased being supported April 2012. The repositories are likely not hosted by Canonical anymore.

Comment: They are all hosted... http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

Comment: I`ve made the same operation on Debian 7, everything has started to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually download python-stdeb here:

http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-stdeb

The link is at the bottom.

Answer (score -2):

Just install it via pip:

```
pip install python-stdeb
```

If you do not have pip: `apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: The same mistake... "Unable to locate python-pip"